# Как остановить воспроизведение аудио на всех вкладках кроме текущей?

Tags: javascript, html5, web-audio

Допустим пользователь запустил воспроизведение аудио, потом открыл новую вкладку и там опять запустил, нужно поставить аудио на паузу на предыдущей вкладке при активации воспроизведения на текущей. Собственно так сделано в VK.

Answer (score 3):

Похоже немого поспешил с вопросом, немного поискав нашёл информацию о том что **localStorage** имеет [событие](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Window/storage_event): **storage**, о чём я конечно-же раньше не знал...
Событие не срабатывает на текущей вкладке, или окне, но срабатывает на остальных, что мне как раз и требуется... Все это выглядит следующим образом:

```
window.addEventListener('storage', function(event) {
    //Действие которое нужно выполнить на вкладках/окнах, кроме текущей
});
```

Сработает при манипуляции с **localStorage**.

Может кому-то будет полезно.

Comment: Спасибо! Тоже не знал. Очень просто и удобно.

Comment: @JohnDoe, Пожалуйста) Сколько работал с localStorage, но не знал что существует событие)))

Comment: Тег <embed src="sound.mp3"></embed> не может играть одновременно в нескольких вкладдках, только в той, которая в данный момент активна.

Answer (score 2):

## как передать сообщение между вкладками ?

### window.postMessage

- window.postMessage - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage
- https://caniuse.com/#feat=mdn-api_window_postmessage

### sharedWorker, webWorker, serviceWorker

- sharedWorker - https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/SharedWorker
- webWorker - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers
- serviceWorker - https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Service_Worker_API
- https://caniuse.com/#feat=webworkers,sharedworkers,serviceworkers

### BroadcastChannel

- broadcastchannel - https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/BroadcastChannel
- https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/09/broadcastchannel
- https://caniuse.com/#search=broadcastchannel

```js
// index.html
const channel = new BroadcastChannel('my_bus')
channel.postMessage('hello world')
channel.onmessage = function (e) {
    document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', `Received: ${e.data}<br>`)
}
window.addEventListener('beforeunload', () => {
    channel.postMessage('bye bye')
    channel.close()
})
```